# How to know the class of an object at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift

I don't understand why I could not find this question somewhere as I think it's a pretty common one so maybe I'm not well awake. Sorry for that if it's the case.

I have my `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)` function and I cannot find out what class is `sender`. I don't want to try every classes of the `Foundation` framework so is there a way to know it at runtime.

When I use the debugger I only get `(AnyObject!) sender = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = ...` which doesn't really help.

Comment: Why do you need the class of the sender?

Comment: Because I trying to make an interective transition on the row of my tableview and if I'm not wrong I need the position of the start of the gesture to get the index of the row. And as I don't know what object is my sender, I don't know how to get the location...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you know the class and you just need to cast. If that's the case, use `as`: `let cell = sender as UITableViewCell`.

Comment: No actually I don't know the class that. I thought it would be something like a UIGestureRecognizer but it's not. That's why I want to know if there is a way to know what type of Class is sender at runtime

Answer (score 2):

Instead of asking the object for its class, I find it more "Swifty" to use "if let" to check if it is what I am looking for.

```
func inputUnknown(sender : AnyObject) {
   if let tableView = sander as? UITableView {
      // now you have an object with a defined class
   }
   else {
      // check for other classes or proceed with a default action
   }
}
```

Comment: agreed, that's what I advised Nico to do in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Every object has an underlying `dynamicType` property, which, in theory, should reveal the actual type of the object, when printed to the console. However, Swift doesn't yet have support for printable metatypes, so you'll get `ExistentialMetatype` for an instance's `dynamicType` and `MetaType` for a class's type. In order to get around this, you can cast your `Type` variable to `AnyObject`, which, when printed to your console will print the Objective C metatype.

```
if let object = sender {
    println(object.dynamicType as AnyObject)
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error : Cannot downcast from 'AnyObject!.Type' to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'

Comment: hmm, it might need to be implicitly unwrapped. I just made an edit, try that instead.

Comment: it works but you need to add a "?" after sender. Thanks. So there is no way to know exactly what type of class is an object AnyObject at runtime?

Comment: maybe I don't understand what you mean by 'know', because isn't this letting you 'know' what class it is? What's the behavior you're ultimately looking for.

Comment: I see what the issue was. prepareForSegue has an optional sender. Sorry about the oversight.

Comment: when I do println(sender?.dynamicType as AnyObject!) I get Menu.MenuTransitionManager

Comment: That's the class of your `sender` object, then. What were you expecting?

Comment: Then maybe I don't get it right but when I click on an UIButton for example. Sender is an UIButton, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72499/discussion-between-blacksquare-and-nico).